# how to convert milliseconds to date format in android?

Tags: java, android, android-date, date

I have milliseconds. 
I need it to be converted to date format of

example:

> 23/10/2011

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 243, accepted):

Just Try this Sample code:-

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class Test {

/**
 * Main Method
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getDate(82233213123L, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS"));
}


/**
 * Return date in specified format.
 * @param milliSeconds Date in milliseconds
 * @param dateFormat Date format 
 * @return String representing date in specified format
 */
public static String getDate(long milliSeconds, String dateFormat)
{
    // Create a DateFormatter object for displaying date in specified format.
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);

    // Create a calendar object that will convert the date and time value in milliseconds to date. 
     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
     return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
}
}
```

Comment: it works on over 10 digit long value but not on 6 downward. hour have a default of 4.. ???

Comment: you should Use **new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat,Locale.US(_or your locale_))** instead of **new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat)**, because it's causes crash due the change default android language

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: @Uttam this works thanks!, But i had a question. Should we receive time and date in this "/Date(1224043200000)/" format? I've read that its an old json format of microsoft and it should not be used in new development.

Answer (score 98):

Convert the *millisecond* value to `Date` instance and pass it to the choosen formatter.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(dateInMillis)));
```

Answer (score 42):

```
public static String convertDate(String dateInMilliseconds,String dateFormat) {
    return DateFormat.format(dateFormat, Long.parseLong(dateInMilliseconds)).toString();
}
```

Call this function

```
convertDate("82233213123","dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Thanks Mahmood, this solution requires API Level 1 (my project is lowered to API 15) while other Answer requires API Level 24 (Date and/or Calendar library)

Comment: what if you're american?

Comment: @SteveRogers this will allow backward compatibility https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring

Answer (score 18):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( myMillisSinceEpoch )           // Convert count-of-milliseconds-since-epoch into a date-time in UTC (`Instant`).
    .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )           // Adjust into the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone). Produces a `ZonedDateTime` object.
    .toLocalDate()                                   // Extract the date-only value (a `LocalDate` object) from the `ZonedDateTime` object, without time-of-day and without time zone.
    .format(                                         // Generate a string to textually represent the date value.
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" )  // Specify a formatting pattern. Tip: Consider using `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalized…` instead to soft-code the formatting pattern.
    )                                                // Returns a `String` object.
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes used by all the other Answers.

Assuming you have a `long` number of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z…

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( myMillisSinceEpoch ) ;
```

To get a date requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;  // Same moment, different wall-clock time.
```

Extract a date-only value.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Generate a String representing that value using standard ISO 8601 format.

```
String output = ld.toString() ;
```

Generate a String in custom format.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ;
String output = ld.format( f ) ;
```

Tip: Consider letting *java.time* automatically localize for you rather than hard-code a formatting pattern. Use the `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalized…` methods.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 14):

```
DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(dateInMS);
```

Answer (score 13):

try this code might help, modify it suit your needs

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date d = format.parse(fileDate);
```

Answer (score 8):

i finally find normal code that works for me

```
Long longDate = Long.valueOf(date);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int offset = cal.getTimeZone().getOffset(cal.getTimeInMillis());
Date da = new Date(); 
da = new Date(longDate-(long)offset);
cal.setTime(da);

String time =cal.getTime().toLocaleString(); 
//this is full string        

time = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM).format(da);
//this is only time

time = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM).format(da);
//this is only date
```

Answer (score 7):

Short and effective:

```
DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date(myMillisValue))
```

Answer (score 5):

Coverting epoch format to SimpleDateFormat in Android (Java / Kotlin)

input: 1613316655000

output: 2021-02-14T15:30:55.726Z

In Java

```
long milliseconds = 1613316655000L;
Date date = new Date(milliseconds);
String mobileDateTime = Utils.getFormatTimeWithTZ(date);
```

//method that returns SimpleDateFormat in String

```
public static String getFormatTimeWithTZ(Date currentTime) {
    SimpleDateFormat timeZoneDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.getDefault());
    return timeZoneString = timeZoneDate.format(currentTime);
}
```

In Kotlin

```
var milliseconds = 1613316655000L
var date = Date(milliseconds)
var mobileDateTime = Utils.getFormatTimeWithTZ(date)
```

//method that returns SimpleDateFormat in String

```
fun getFormatTimeWithTZ(currentTime:Date):String {
  val timeZoneDate = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.getDefault())
  return timeZoneString = timeZoneDate.format(currentTime)
}
```

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 5):

Latest solution in **Kotlin**:

```
private fun getDateFromMilliseconds(millis: Long): String {
    val dateFormat = "MMMMM yyyy"
    val formatter = SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.getDefault())
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    
    calendar.timeInMillis = millis
    return formatter.format(calendar.time)
}
```

We need to add **Locale** as an argument of **SimpleDateFormat** or use **LocalDate**. **Locale.getDefault()** is a great way to let **JVM** automatically get the current location timezone.

Answer (score 4):

```
public class LogicconvertmillistotimeActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     EditText millisedit;
        Button   millisbutton;
        TextView  millistextview;
        long millislong;
        String millisstring;
        int millisec=0,sec=0,min=0,hour=0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        millisedit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        millisbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        millistextview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        millisbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {   
                millisbutton.setClickable(false);
                millisec=0;
                sec=0;
                min=0;
                hour=0;
                millisstring=millisedit.getText().toString().trim();
                millislong= Long.parseLong(millisstring);
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                if(millislong>1000){
                    sec=(int) (millislong/1000);
                    millisec=(int)millislong%1000;
                    if(sec>=60){
                        min=sec/60;
                        sec=sec%60;
                    }
                    if(min>=60){
                        hour=min/60;
                        min=min%60;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    millisec=(int)millislong;
                }
                cal.clear();
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,min);
                cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, sec);
                cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,millisec);
                String DateFormat = formatter.format(cal.getTime());
//              DateFormat = "";
                millistextview.setText(DateFormat);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: We can do it by using Time Unit..but it doesn't works fine...use this..this will help you..it works fine

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking for an efficient way to do this for quite some time and the best I've found is:

```
DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(new Date(millis));
```

Advantages:

1. It's localized
2. Been in Android since API 1
3. Very simple

Disadvantages:

1. Limited format options.  FYI:  SHORT is only a 2 digit year.
2. You burn a Date object every time.  I've looked at source for the other options and this is a fairly minor compared to their overhead.

You can cache the java.text.DateFormat object, but it's not threadsafe.  This is OK if you are using it on the UI thread.

Answer (score 3):

This is the easiest way using Kotlin

```
private const val DATE_FORMAT = "dd/MM/yy hh:mm"

fun millisToDate(millis: Long) : String {
    return SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT, Locale.US).format(Date(millis))
}
```

Comment: (1) Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android use desugaring or see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: (2) I don’t think you intended lower case `hh`? Please check the difference between upper case and lower case here.

Comment: The modern way is: `return Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT, Locale.US))`. Yes, it’s longer because it gives more information about what is going on, so it’s an advantage.

Comment: @OleV.V. Call requires API level 26

Comment: @RupamDas Either use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, on older Android versions (under API level 26).

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static Date getDateFromString(String date) {

    Date dt = null;
    if (date != null) {
        for (String sdf : supportedDateFormats) {
            try {
                dt = new Date(new SimpleDateFormat(sdf).parse(date).getTime());
                break;
            } catch (ParseException pe) {
                pe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return dt;
}

public static Calendar getCalenderFromDate(Date date){
    Calendar cal =Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);return cal;

}
public static Calendar getCalenderFromString(String s_date){
    Date date = getDateFromString(s_date);
    Calendar cal = getCalenderFromDate(date);
    return cal;
}

public static long getMiliSecondsFromString(String s_date){
    Date date = getDateFromString(s_date);
    Calendar cal = getCalenderFromDate(date);
    return cal.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

Comment: Use these method to convert date in string format like 2016-08-18 or any type of in string format to DateFormat and you can also convert date into milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String toDateStr(long milliseconds, String format)
{
    Date date = new Date(milliseconds);
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
    return formatter.format(date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SimpleDateFormat for Android N and above. Use the calendar for earlier versions
for example:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hh:mm:ss").format(new Date());
        Log.i("fileName before",fileName);
    }else{
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH,1);
        String zamanl =""+cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-"+cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"-"+cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"-"+cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

        fileName= zamanl;
        Log.i("fileName after",fileName);
    }
```

*Output:*
fileName before: 2019-04-12-07:14:47  *// use SimpleDateFormat*
fileName after: 2019-4-12-7:13:12         *// use Calender*

Answer (score 0):

```
fun convertLongToTimeWithLocale(){
    val dateAsMilliSecond: Long = 1602709200000
    val date = Date(dateAsMilliSecond)
    val language = "en"
    val formattedDateAsDigitMonth = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale(language))
    val formattedDateAsShortMonth = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale(language))
    val formattedDateAsLongMonth = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", Locale(language))
    Log.d("month as digit", formattedDateAsDigitMonth.format(date))
    Log.d("month as short", formattedDateAsShortMonth.format(date))
    Log.d("month as long", formattedDateAsLongMonth.format(date))
}
```

output:

```
month as digit: 15/10/2020
month as short: 15 Oct 2020 
month as long : 15 October 2020
```

You can change the value defined as 'language' due to your require. Here is the all language codes:
[Java language codes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/marketing/crowdtwist-develop/Content/Developers/LanguageCodes.html)

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.