# how to get date from milliseconds in android

Tags: android, datetime, android-date

I have time in `milliseconds`, now I want to **separate** `time` and `date` from these `milliseconds`.

how can i do this???

Comment: Can you show the form which you have?

Comment: I found best solution in this answer

http://stackoverflow.com/a/7954038/1677835

Comment: @SergeyPekar While that was a good answer back then, it is using the old and poorly designed classes `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. It’s been a very long time since that was recommended.

Comment: @OleV.V. as you see 4 years passed since my answer :-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you can use like this

```
Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance();
cl.setTimeInMillis(milliseconds);  //here your time in miliseconds
String date = "" + cl.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + ":" + cl.get(Calendar.MONTH) + ":" + cl.get(Calendar.YEAR);
String time = "" + cl.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + cl.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + cl.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Comment: It is showing wrong month. We’re in April, and I get 3. Also, while using `Calendar` was a good idea in 2012, it isn’t anymore. We’ve got a lot better in [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I am late but yea for anyone wondering...if I am not wrong, in the Calendar class, 0 = January and not 1, so it is not showing the wrong month actually. But understandably, it can be confusing.

Answer (score 20):

This function will give you a String date from milliseconds

```
public static String getFormattedDateFromTimestamp(long timestampInMilliSeconds)
{
    Date date = new Date(); 
    date.setTime(timestampInMilliSeconds);
    String formattedDate=new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy").format(date);
    return formattedDate;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Convert the `milliseconds` to `Date` instance and pass it to the chosen formatter:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

String myDate = dateFormat.format(new Date(dateInMillis)));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) to get the values of different time fields:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int monthOfYear = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the milliseconds to a date object and then extract date in the format of a time string and another string of just the date

Comment: i didn't even mean `Date()` specifically but no it isn't, not yet, and not for these purposes. don't confuse everyone else.

Comment: just `setTime` is not deprecated. other methods (most of them) are deprecated. So why involve `Date` to just set the time? Why not use `Calnedar class`

Comment: i have no agenda with any specific class. but if some methods are still working fine for what i need and are clearly not deprecated, i don't throw the baby out with the bathwater.

Comment: yes but after `setTime`. When he is going to retrieve the date..then again he has no option^^ other then using the `Calender` class. Why not adopt a new born baby!

Answer (score 0):

Further to Kiran Kumar Answer

```
 public static String getFormattedDateFromTimestamp(long timestampInMilliSeconds, String dateStyle){
        Date date = new Date(); 
        date.setTime(timestampInMilliSeconds);
        String formattedDate=new SimpleDateFormat(dateStyle).format(date);
        return formattedDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

I suggest java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work:

```
    long millisecondsSinceEpoch = 1_567_890_123_456L;

    ZonedDateTime dateTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millisecondsSinceEpoch)
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    LocalDate date = dateTime.toLocalDate();
    LocalTime time = dateTime.toLocalTime();

    System.out.println("Date: " + date);
    System.out.println("Time: " + time);
```

Output in my time zone (Europe/Copenhagen):

> ```
> Date: 2019-09-07
> Time: 23:02:03.456
> ```

The date and time classes used in the other answers — `Calendar`, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` — are poorly designed and long outdated. This is why I don’t recommend using any of them but prefer java.time.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Date format and set your millisecond value as a parameter to this constructor, Follow this code:

```
SimpleDateFormat SDF= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
String date = SDF.format(new Date(millies)));
```

Comment: The question already has an accepted answer. Also your answer needs educational explanation.