# How to convert long to datetime in android

Tags: java, android, datetime, long-integer

Datetime value in long variable need to convert to  this format `2014-04-06T12:04:23.000Z`
what is the simplest approach.

Comment: Check SimpleDateFormat. It works on patterns and is really easy to use. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Here you'll find an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953725/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-date-format-in-android

Comment: @markubik, Hi, thanks but the response is in string i.e simpledateformat, how to convert to datetime?

Comment: Date type has constructor that takes String as argument.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the `long` is the usual value (milliseconds since The Epoch), you create a `Date` instance:

```
Date theDate = new Date(theLongValue);
```

...and then use one of the `DateFormat`s (perhaps `SimpleDateFormat`) or something like JodaTime to format the result however you want.

If you're using Java 8, you might check out the new [`java.time` package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), which provides a new and hopefully better API for dates and times; [Oracle tutorial here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3):

Try this simply way,

#### Android

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.US);

System.out.format("%30s %s\n", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", sdf.format(new Date(0))); // 0 - your "LongValue"
```

#### Result

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000
```

Great Android **Doc** for [**SimpleDateFormat**](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use `SimpleDateFormat`

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
Date outputDate = format.parse(inputDate);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but the response is in string, wont it be in datetime?

Comment: sorry, i exploded the function to have Date as output