# Convert from milliseconds to MM:ss.mmm (Java)

Tags: java, math, time

I need to create a method with the following signature:

```
public String getPrintTime (int t);
```

t represents time in milliseconds ranging 1-5120000.
The output needs to be in the format MM:ss:mmm.
For example:

```
getPrintTime(2342819) == 39:02.819

getPrintTime(23) == 00:00.023

getPrintTime(2340000) == 39:00.000
```

I have tried in many ways but couldn't get it to work in all of the cases.

Comment: Take a look at DateFormat class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html

Comment: That argument needs to be a `long` rather than an `int`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert milliseconds to date format in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953725/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-date-format-in-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for this. Note, however, that the correct format string is not `MM:ss.mmm` but `mm:ss.SSS`.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss.SSS");
String formatted = sdf.format(new Date(t));
```

Alternatively, roll your own with simple division, modulo, and [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
int minutes = t /(1000 * 60);
int seconds = t / 1000 % 60;
int millis  = t % 1000;
String formatted = String.format("%02d:%02d.%03d", minutes, seconds, millis);
```