# How to set universal timings for Android app

Tags: javascript, database, mobile

I am doing mobile app which should be used world wide to set universal timing. for example I am in us then that app will take US timings and if the app is used in japan automatically that timing setting changes. that logic I want to write in db or script.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a UTC/UT/GMT time. If you don't care that users might change the handset time, then you can use [System.currentTimeMillis()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) Which is milliseconds since January 1st, 1970 in UTC. Then you can just convert that to a date as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953725/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-date-format-in-android).

When you later create a date using the UTC time, it will automatically be converted to the current time zone of the system/device. Like [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953725/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-date-format-in-android).

If you don't trust users (and why would you?) you might want to hit a time server and get the current UTC time.