# Android Date Format Conversion from millis to date and time

Tags: java, android, datetime

I am building sunshine app using volley library. I successfully parse data but I am unable to format date. I am getting date from api in millis. I use original code method of sunshine to format date but still getting date as 18 Jan 1970.
JSON field dt: 1484856000
I want to convert it in original date and then in string like today, tomorrow.

Comment: This looks like second not ms, so multiply by 1000.  Then use SimpleDateFormat to format as reuired

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953725/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-date-format-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Check http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html

```
public String getFormattedDate(Context context, long smsTimeInMilis) {
Calendar smsTime = Calendar.getInstance();
smsTime.setTimeInMillis(smsTimeInMilis);

Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

final String timeFormatString = "h:mm aa";
final String dateTimeFormatString = "EEEE, MMMM d, h:mm aa";
final long HOURS = 60 * 60 * 60;
if (now.get(Calendar.DATE) == smsTime.get(Calendar.DATE) ) {
    return "Today " + DateFormat.format(timeFormatString, smsTime);
} else if (now.get(Calendar.DATE) - smsTime.get(Calendar.DATE) == 1  ){
    return "Yesterday " + DateFormat.format(timeFormatString, smsTime);
} else if (now.get(Calendar.YEAR) == smsTime.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
    return DateFormat.format(dateTimeFormatString, smsTime).toString();
} else {
    return DateFormat.format("MMMM dd yyyy, h:mm aa", smsTime).toString();
}
```

}