# Getting confused with java.util.Calendar

Tags: android, date, calendar, java.util.calendar

I want to get the date of SMS in format dd-MM-yyyy and time in format HH:MM (in 24hr format) on which it was received on phone. I use the following code

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(messages[0].getTimestampMillis());
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS");
String finalDateString = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
Log.i(TAG, "Date new Format " + finalDateString);
```

Message was recieved on 11:50PM on 26-Dec-19 at phone, but I get the result in Log "Date new Format 27/12/2019 10:50:03.000". Please notice instead of 26 its giving 27 and time is also 1 hr less, instead of 11 its 10. 
Is this a normal behaviour? Do I have to subtract 1 day from date to get correct data and add 1 hr in time? Will this always work correctly? Do I have to specify timezone to get correct data? Please advise as I got confused with ths.

Comment: It’s scaringly easy to get confused about `java.util.Calendar`. And `SimpleDateFormat` is even worse. Consider throwing away those long outmoded and poorly designed classes, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: It’s a time zone issue. Which time zone are you in?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to convert milliseconds to date format in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953725/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-date-format-in-android) I recommend [the answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49378569/5772882).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as follow

```
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
```